# Python function definition not working

Tags: python, function, definition

I've got a problem with a function which is defined in a Python class:

```
class DatabaseHandler:

    def get_messages_by_last_mid(self, uidReceiver, last_mid):

        self.cursor.execute("SELECT uidSender, content FROM messages WHERE MID > ?", str(last_mid))

        ret_value = []
        result = self.cursor.fetchone()
        while result != None:
            ret_value.append(result)
            result = self.cursor.fetchone()

        return ret_value

    def get_messages_by_last_group_id(self, uidReceiver, last_gid):

        self.cursor.execute("SELECT gidreceiver, uidsender, content FROM groupmessages WHERE mid > ?", str(last_gid))

        ret_value = []
        result = self.cursor.fetchone()
        while result != None:
           ret_value.append(result)
           result = self.cursor.fetchone()

        return ret_value
```

But only the function get_messages_by_last_mid() works, the other one produces the following error:

```
AttributeError: DatabaseHandler instance has no attribute 'get_messages_by_last_group_id'
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Your indentation is wrong. Is this how your code is indented in your actual source file? If so, that would cause problems.

Comment: Your class's constructor seems to be missing. If `get_messages_by_last_mid()` works, then `self` is getting a `cursor` attribute from somewhere, though. Is this your whole `DatabaseHandler` class?

Comment: Indentation is now the same as in source file.
It also contains an constructor:
`def __init__(self, database):
    self.db = sqlite3.connect(database)
    self.db.text_factory = str`

Answer (score 1):

Indentation can be a silent killer in Python if you're coming from various other programming languages. As you already know, indentation is how Python determines the scope of methods, functions, classes, loops, etc. as you write your code. Make sure your indentation is consistent!  You can use the command-line option -t or -tt to python to check yourself.

Comment: The class DatabaseHandler is installed as a Python module. As I already answered, `python -t DatabaseHandler.py` does not return anything

Answer (score 1):

Sorry guys, I had used an old package.
My problem has been fixed.
Thanks for your answers.